# Open Protocol and Data Transparant Transmission on M210 and M600

Tags: dji-sdk

The following page

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/Protocol-Documents/main.html

indicates that the Open Protocol and Data Transparent Transmission are not available for the M210 and M600. Is this true? Are there alternatives for these drones?

I would need these features to send custom data and commands between the Mobile SDK and the Onboard SDK.

Best regards,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

I cant speak for the Open Protocol or the M210 but the M600 uses a DJI A3 flight controller which I currently have installed on a custom quadcopter. And I can successfully send commands using the data transmission protocol between the mobile SDK and the Onboard ROS SDK.

An alternative would be to buy the N3/A3 flight controller and just build your own custom drone.